ffmpeg library resizing and uploading output file in the folder on localh but on server file doesn't upload after resizing
Here is my function:
try {
        if (!empty($_FILES['file2'])) {
            $files = true;
            // Handle the file uploads
            $files2 = $_FILES['file2'];
            $maxFileSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024; // 500 MB in bytes
            foreach ($files2['name'] as $key2 => $value2) {
                if ($files2['error'][$key2] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                    if ($files2['size'][$key2] <= $maxFileSize) {
                    $job_file = $files2['name'][$key2];
                    $inputFile = $files2['tmp_name'][$key2];
                    $file_name = pathinfo($job_file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                    $compress_file = $file_name . '.mp4';
                    $filepath = '../assets/files/' . $compress_file;
                    // move_uploaded_file($files2['tmp_name'][$key2], $filepath);
                    $ffmpeg_path = '../assets/vendor/libs/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg';
                    $command = sprintf('%s -i %s -vf scale=640:360 -crf 28 -preset fast %s',
                    escapeshellarg($ffmpeg_path),
                    escapeshellarg($inputFile),
                    escapeshellarg($filepath)
                    );
                   $output = shell_exec($command);
                   $job_file_column2[] = $compress_file;
                } else {
                        $upload_errors = true;
                        $errors[] = 'Error: Video size exceeds 500 MB '. ($key2 + 1). ': '. $files2['name'][$key2];
                    }
                } else {
                    $upload_errors = true;
                    $errors[] =  'Error uploading file ' . ($key2 + 1) . ': ' . $files2['name'][$key2];
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
    }

The file was resized and uploaded on localhost, but on live server it's not uploading the file in folder. I also tried another folder, but it's not working.

Why is this using move_uploaded_file? That function checks if the file it is supposed to move, is actually the result of a file upload - which yours here surely isn't. If there is anything to be surprised about here to begin with, then how this was supposedly working on localhost - it rather shouldn't have. Use rename, if you want to move an arbitrary file from one location to another.

@CBroe even if i remove move_uploaded_file but file still uploaded in localhost. i edit the code
